# How to connect to a database using SSH connection type using Oracle SQLPlus?

Tags: database, oracle, ssh, sqlplus, database-administration

I need to connect to a database which can be accessed only through a jump server.

I can access this easily using the SSH host setup using the key file (pem file) and then adding the connection with connection type of SSH in Oracle SQL Developer.

But what I would like is to connect the same database using SQLPlus rather than using SQLDeveloper.

I searched for this in many questions and blogs but couldn't get a proper answer but most of the answers were around the SQLDeveloper setups for this than SQLPlus.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If You've got a jump host, use [port forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436290/single-step-ssh-port-forwarding-not-working-but-only-works-when-ssh-port-forward)  by creating ssh tunnels. This will allow you to use your local host name and port in your SQL* Plus connection string.

Comment: Thanks Kaushik. I will give this a try.

Comment: The [port forwarding] (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436290/single-step-ssh-port-forwarding-not-working-but-only-works-when-ssh-port-forward) you shared was good. This helped me as well. Basically its a similar concept of connecting with SQL Developer. Thanks @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

- *Ahost*: Your Machine
- *Bhost*: Jump Box
- *Chost*: DB Server

Default port:1521

Tunnel port:1621 (just for the example)

Then if you want to connect with SQLPlus running on *Ahost*, then you need to establish a connection from [*Ahost*] to [*Bhost*] with a tunnel to [*Chost*] this way:

`ssh -NL 1621:Chost:1621 Bhost`
-> just leave the session running there.

then you can start a connection with sqlplus with destination host:port as localhost:1621

if you are using Putty you can achieve this by using:
[SSH -> Tunnels option under the SSH session options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgxeK.png)

Comment: In my case the command is like; `ssh -NL 1621:db_host:1521 user@tunnel_host -p 2222` 2222 is custom ssh port, if anyone needs. 1521 db port, 1621 custom local port

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use CMAN, CMAN can allow remote conections from a intermediate Server to the database server, this acts like a proxy server.

Thanks.